# Store Lambda expressions as variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to store a lambda expression as a variable and use it in multiple places.
My db objects have an *Id* as int and a *UId* as an uniqueidentifier and I have to write very similar expressions when selecting based on *Id* or *UId*.

**Lambda**:

```
var result = await this.Worker.GetRepo<Category>().DbSet
    .Include(cat => cat.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.GraphicItems)
            .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Graphic)
                .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
    .Include(cat => cat.GraphicItems)
        .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Graphic)
            .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
    .Include(m => m.Modules)
    .SingleAsync(cat => cat.Id.Equals(id));
```

Is it possible to:

```
var expression = .Include(cat => cat.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.InfoItems)
    .Include(cat => cat.Products)
        .ThenInclude(prd => prd.GraphicItems)
            .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Graphic)
                .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
    .Include(cat => cat.GraphicItems)
        .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Graphic)
            .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
    .Include(m => m.Modules);
```

then use the variable like:

```
await this.Worker.GetRepo<Category>().expression.SingleAsync(cat => cat.Id.Equals(id));

await this.Worker.GetRepo<Category>().expression.SingleAsync(cat => cat.UId.Equals(uid));
```

> I know the syntax is wrong, it's just what I'm looking for.

Comment: You may want to look at `Func<T, TResult>` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) which should allow you to do what you want.

Comment: @Chris, Or sometimes [`Expression<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), that is `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>`, since some flavors of Linq need an expression tree, to be translated into e.g. SQL, and cannot use a plain .NET delegate instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just create a method that returns an `IQueryable<Category>`. If you want the usage to be the same as your example then this could be an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static IQueryable<Category> GetExpression(this IQueryable<Category> qry)
{
    var expression = qry.Include(cat => cat.InfoItems)
        .Include(cat => cat.Products)
            .ThenInclude(prd => prd.InfoItems)
        .Include(cat => cat.Products)
            .ThenInclude(prd => prd.GraphicItems)
                .ThenInclude(itm => itm.Graphic)
                    .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
        .Include(cat => cat.GraphicItems)
            .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Graphic)
                .ThenInclude(gfx => gfx.Items)
        .Include(m => m.Modules);

    return expression;
}
```

You can then use this as follows:

```
await this.Worker
    .GetRepo<Category>()
    .GetExpression()
    .SingleAsync(cat => cat.UId.Equals(uid));
```